# Big data creation from normal database table

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

We have application which contains one table with transactional data which we keep referring every day. It has millions of rows. Obviously querying that table is very slow.

Is there any way through which I can create bigdata from that table and use hadoop and relevant technology to query the result?

Comment: "It has millions of rows. Obviously querying that table is very slow" - then you might be doing something incorrectly. Do you have the appropriate indexes?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache Sqoop, to import the big database in Hadoop.
Everday at the end ( or as per your own scheule ) you can import transactions which were done into exisitng database you loaded. So in this way everyday you will add the transactions to exisitng data inside Hadoop.

Technologies you need to see

Sqoop : To import data from Database 
Hive : To provide SQL like interface to query that data  Search Apache Hive
Oozie : To shedule the job to import data everyday.  Search Apache oozie
Sqoop has feature of doing incremental loads which you can use.

Other than Hive you can use Impala to query the data , it works very fast